# MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection with no collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Why I'm getting this error!!

> GOOGLE USER:  null
> /Users//my-blog/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/insert.js:53
> return callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(res.writeErrors[0]));
> ^
>
> MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: blog.users
> index: email_1 dup key: { email: "" }

I dropped the whole collection in Mongodb and when I tried again it gave me the same error but the data stored in MongoDB collection, the problem is with the error it stops the whole app from running. I don't know where I went wrong or what I'm missing.

**`Auth.js` Code:**

```
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { 
  scope: ["profile", "email"] }));

router.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google", {
  successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/",
  failureRedirect: "/googleLogin/failed"
}));

router.get("/googleLogin/success", async (req, res)=>{
  if(req.user){
    const user = await User.findOne({provider_id: req.user.id, 
      provider: req.user.provider})
    if(user){
       res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "success",
        user: user
      })
      console.log("GOOGLE USER IS: " + user)
    }else{
      const checkUserEmail = await User.findOne({email: req.user.email})
      if(checkUserEmail){
        res.status(401).json({
          success: false,
          message: "User already Exist with this email id",
        })
      }else{
        const user = await User.create({
          username: req.user.name.givenName+ "_" +req.user.name.familyName,
          firstName: req.user.name.givenName,
          lastName: req.user.name.familyName,
          email: req.user.emails[0].value,
          provider: req.user.provider,
          provider_id: req.user.id,
          // profilePic: req.user.photos?.[0]?.value,
        });
         res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: "success",
          user: user
        })
      }
    }
    console.log("GOOGLE USER: ", user);
  }
})

router.get("/googleLogin/failed", (req, res)=>{
  if(req.user){
    res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "failure",
    })
  }
})
```

I THINK the code keeps running nonstop ! thats why it giving me the error even so the collection is empty, it sign up the user then it sign up again non stop. I think that it should be a done() in the code but I didn't know how to fix it.

**`Passport.js` Setup:**

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
  passReqToCallback: true,
  scope: ["profile", "email"],
},
function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
console.log(profile.emails[0].value);
console.log(profile.photos[0].value);

  return done(null, profile)
}
));

passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
  done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser((user, done)=>{
  done(null, user)
})
```

**Here is my User Schema: `User.js`**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        /* Can't create a user with the same username */
        unique: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 30,
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: false,
        maxlength: 20,
      },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: false,
      },
    email: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    repeatPassword: {
        type: String,
    },
    profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
    },
    birthday: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      unique: false,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        unique: false,
    },
    googleId: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        default: "email"
      },
      provider_id: {
        type: String,
      }
},
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Show your `User` schema.

Comment: I agree with robertklep. they must be some field in your schema which has `unique: true` property. when you first get `null` or `undefined` value it saved it and other requests with `null` or `undefined` are getting rejected and throwing error.

Comment: @robertklep I edited the question with the link to my user schema

Comment: @RustamjonKirgizbaev I edited the question with the link to my user schema

Comment: Please add the schema to your question instead of posting it on a remote site.

Comment: You see there is `unique: true` in your schema and using `username: req.user.name.givenName+ "_" +req.user.name.familyName` is not a good idea because there are people with the same name and surname. Besides at that point you may be getting `null` or `undefined`. Just to test you can remove `unique: true` if everything works fine you will find the root cause.